# Unused variable warning

Tags: java

I have created two classes, one for the defining all the properties and other for the main method to initialized the object.

First class:

```
package basketball;

public class Basktball {
    public String name;             //instance variables
    public String color;
    public int bounceRate;

    public String getName() {       //getters & setters
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getBounceRate() {
        return bounceRate;
    }

    public void setBounceRate(int bounceRate) {
        this.bounceRate = bounceRate;
    }

    public void bounces() {
        System.out.println("bounces");
    }

    public void defleats() {
        System.out.println("defleats....");
    }
}
```

Second class for main method:

```
package basketball;

public class Ball {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basktball ball = new Basktball();   
    }
}
```

Here in `main` I got a problem while calling the object says

> local variable ball is not used

and also I can't call all the object which I have created.

Comment: What you see is a warning, not an error. You should still investigate warnings, though, cause usually the compiler is right. In this case you create and initialize that `ball` variable, but you don't do anything with it. You should call some of its method, e.g., `ball.defleats();`.

Comment: please show me how to create

Comment: You can't "call" an object. It's not very clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: You have declared an instance of the **Basktball** object to a variable named **ball** but you don't use the variable **ball** anywhere in your code. The warning is just letting you know that....`"If you don't intend to use the variable **ball** anywhere in your code, why did you waste the time to declare it to begin with. Maybe you're forgetting something"`. You don't need to use the variable, after all it is just a warning but it does shine a brighter light on the initial question as to: "Why did you declare it if you're not going to use it?"

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple warning, and you see this because in main method you have created the ball reference variable to hold an object of Basktball, but never used it any further.

Warnings can be safely ignored, and donot cause the program to malfunction. However, if you want to get rid of above warning, just add System.out.println(ball); at the end of main method.

Secondly to access any of the instance variables / methods use dot operator. For e.g. ball.getName(), ball.getColor().